# Замена новой строки на  с пом PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Есть текстовое поле. Если писать слова с новой строки, то все нормально заносится в БД и от туда выводится. Но браузеры не понимают знака новой строки. Им нуден `<br />` Как правильно заменить новую строку на тег `<br />`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хотите средствами php, то можно использовать **nl2br()**

> nl2br — Вставляет HTML-код разрыва
> строки перед каждым переводом строки
>
> Возвращает строку string, в которой
> перед каждым переводом строки (\r\n,> \n\r, \n и \r) вставлен '< br />' или
> '< br >'.

Текствые данные которые выводятся из поля text mysql, можно помещать в nl2br().

Answer (score 1):

На JS так:

```
var text = "Текст\nиз\nнескольких\nстрок";
var reg = /\n/gi;
text = text.replace(reg,"<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Но браузеры не понимают знака новой строки.

Все они превосходно понимают.

Вариант 1.

```
<pre>
Some
text
</pre>
```

Вариант 2.

```
<div style="white-space: pre;">
Some
text
</div>
```